# How to change Mongoid db details in Rails without having to restart the machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Ok, I got a problem which seems very odd to me. Whenever I change db settings in `mongoid.yml` file, the changes won't be reflected (like doing a `rails c` and executing some code like `Model.count`) until I restart my computer.

Is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: Do you use `spring`? You might want to stop/restart it (`spring stop`)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you! Do you want to add as a reply so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this kind of problem is often caused by application preloader (like `spring`) bugging out and not properly reloading changes in application code/config. In case of spring, it is often sufficient to stop it.

```
spring stop
```

BUT I've had a few cases where spring would hang up and refuse to stop. In which case I kill it forcefully

```
killall -9 -m spring
```

(kill every process with "spring" in its name)